# Different Debug Keystores in Eclipse on a per project base?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, keystore

I do need to have different debug keystores for several Android projects. How can I do that with plain Eclipse (no additional tools)?

The problem is that it's not possible to connect different apps, that share the same debug key, to Google Drive. Only one, the first one, works - always.

Currently I debug with release versions but the process to generate the signed apps for each debug cycle is very time consuming.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the debug.keystore location in **Windows > Preferences > Android > Build**. Refer [Signing in Debug mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode). This will, however, affect all the projects in the workspace.

Comment: Thanks - but this was not the question. From my 11 Android apps, three have to do with Google Drive. There's no way to work with Google Drive with three different apps (packages) that share the same key (SHA).

Comment: I understand, that's why I had mentioned the caveat. You will have to have the projects in different workspaces. Other than that, your only option is to use Ant build, which you can also execute from Eclipse. That's my opinion, though. You can wait and see if you get any more responses.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, they changed the APIs & Auth section in the Google Cloud Console. Now there is a Credentials section instead of 'Registered Apps'

In 1 'project' in the Developer Console, I currently have 2 different OAuth entries that have the same debug key sha1, and it works fine. They do of course, have different package names.

Comment: It is possible to register different keystores for some Google APIs (for instance for Maps v2), but the essence of the question is whether it's possible to have Eclipse build using a specific debug keystore on a per-project basis.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to do this through Eclipse, you may want to consider building your app through Ant. A detailed description [can be found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747511/154306).