# How to change the environment variable name and value without admin rights?

Tags: android, windows-7, environment-variables

I am using eclipse and android. Android Default debug keystore location as `C:\users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore` I need to change the Default debug keystore location.

So, I am tried to access the `Advanced System Settings` in windows 7. But I have no admin rights, so i can't access the `Advanced System Settings`. How to change the `environment variable and value without admin rights...`

Comment: Dont you get to choose your own keystore when you build the apk from eclipse.. I dont see what the problem is. Why do you want to change the defualt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019833/how-can-i-specify-location-of-debug-keystore-for-android-ant-debug-builds .. check whether it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I Got a workaround

1. Go to start type-in Accounts then click on user accounts
2. In the left hand side go to change my environment variables
3. here you can add your environment variable name and value for your username.

Comment: That doesn't work now. As Microsoft has fixed it.